# Unification: constant, variable, function

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a small quesion:
Can we unify the following pairs?

> p(X, X) and p(a, Z)

Here X is a constant, a is a variable and Z is again a constant.

I think this unification is not possible because we are substituting same constant X for two different identifiers one is 'a' and the other is Z.

> What is the general rule for unification of variable and constant?

I think variable can't be substituted for constant but constant can be substituted for a variable.

There is another option i.e. to apply unification to a function

> What is the constraint for unify a function with a constant and with a
> variable?

One example is:

> ancestor(X, Y) and ancestor(bill, father(bill))

X can be replaced for the variable bill and Y can be replaced for father(bill).

Please guide me if my concepts are correct.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first-order unification, which you seem to be discussing, that is possible assuming X and Z are variables and a is a constant. I'd suggest you check carefully assumptions about constants, functions, predicates and variables, and do some examples, e.g. on paper with Martelli and Montanari's algorithm or using a logic programming system.

There are various unification algorithms. Unification of p(X, X) and p(a, Z) gives the substitution {a/X, a/Z}. One algorithm is by Martelli and Montanari. It is non-deterministic and involves transformations on multisets of equations, e.g. {p(X, X) = p(a, Z)} => {X = a, X = Z} by term decomposition then {X = a, a = Z} by variable elimination then {X = a, Z = a} by swapping so the variable is on the left side of the equation. It always terminates and produces a most general unifier when one exists that is unique up to renaming of variables.

A variable can be instantiated with a constant but not the converse. In the second example, bill and father(bill) are not variables.

Two functions can be unified if they have have the same function symbol and their subterms can be unified. With most unification algorithms, a function can be unified with a variable if the variable does not occur in the function. This condition is called the "occurs check" and prevents infinite terms, e.g, a substitution {f(X, a),/ X} would give the infinite term f(f(f(..... , a), a), ..., a).